# How use the existing theme for spacing?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello guys and ladies,

I’m trying to add margins above an below a Button.

Here is some relevant code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  progress: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: 'auto',
  },
}));

return (
    <Container>
      <Typography variant="h3" component="h1" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        Scholarships
      </Typography>
      <FilterBar changeSortBy={setSortField} changeSortFormat={setSortDir} />
      {error?.toString() ||
        (loading && <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />) || (
          <ScholarshipList scholarships={scholarships} />
        )}
       <Button mt={3} mb={3} </Button>
    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

In the `material-ui` documentation you find;

```
const theme = {
  spacing: 8,
}

<Box m={-2} /> // margin: -16px;
```

But in my case I want to use the *existing* theme which is referred, I think, in the above `const useStyles = makeStyles (() =>`.

So, how do I use the existing theme the web app is currently using to set margins of 24px above and below the button?

As you can see I have added the necessary `mt={3}` and `mb={3}`. Now, I have to make sure that this results in 24px margins by using the themes spacing which is 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Use makeStyles of MaterialUI -  theme.spacing(3, 0)

here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mirzakhani-5d12h

also page from Matrieal explain about theme.spacing:
https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/

there is a default theme of MaterialUI you can change but it's have his default properties - so the default for theme.spacing is 8.

the spacing is number to define the value when you using spacing in your app.
you can define that spacing = 12 and the you will write for example

padding: theme.spacing(2) - to achive css style of padding: 24px (12 * 2)

you can do like that

```
buttonStyle: {
  margin: theme.spacing(3, 0) // 3 * 8 = 24 = 24px
}
```

and this

```
<Button className={styles.buttonStyle}>
  Button-Text
</Button>
```

[image]

Comment: `Button - margin top-bottom 24px` Is this a comment inside <Button> </Button>? Did you mean

Comment: it's the text in the button, you can change it

Comment: Ahh I see, what about any imports?

Comment: I’m getting ‘styles’ is undefined. So this is why I’m asking about the imports. Which import?

Comment: Please look at the codesandbox link and the whole code be there